# how to change elasticsearch type keyword to array?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```json
POST /jobs/_doc/1/
{
  "test": [["A", "B"], ["C", "A"]]
}
```

```json
GET /jobs/_search/
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": """
          Debug.explain(doc['test.keyword']);
          return 1;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

kibana print to string is "[A, B, C]", how can i get like [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]] in painless script?

i try to change mapping but it cant work always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

You can't via indexed fields.
**BUT** it is possible is you access the source

## Solution

```json
GET 74557564/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }, 
      "script": {
        "source": """
          Debug.explain(params._source['data']);
          return 1;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```